# How to scan a 2d array?

Tags: java, readfile

I am trying to read a file and populate data in a 2d array. But during the scan, when I assigning data into my `MazePoint[][]` array. It gives the following error message.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to MazePoint
```

Code block:

```
public MazePoint[][] readMaze(String fileToRead) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fileByteStream = null; // File input stream
    Scanner inFS= null;                   // Scanner object
    fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(fileToRead);
    inFS= new Scanner(fileByteStream);
    int size = inFS.nextInt();
    MazePoint[][] maze = new MazePoint[size][size];
    while(inFS.hasNext()) {
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < size; column++) {
                maze[row][column] = inFS.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
    return maze;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How does your file structure look. Use `System.out.println` to see your content as it is being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MazePoint is a new type of object(class). So, you can not assign an integer there. But it is possible.

1. Inside your MazePoint class, add a new `value` property with `getter` and `setter`.

```java
class MazePoint {
    private int value;
    // ... other things here

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    // ... other things
}
```

2. And then assign value using the setter method.

```java
public MazePoint[][] readMaze(String fileToRead) throws Exception
{
    FileInputStream fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(fileToRead);; // File input stream
    Scanner inFS= new Scanner(fileByteStream);                  // Scanner object
    int size = inFS.nextInt();
    MazePoint[][] mazePoints = new MazePoint[size][size];
    while(inFS.hasNext()) {
       for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
           for (int column = 0; column < size; column++) {
               mazePoints[row][column] = new MazePoint();
               mazePoints[row][column].setValue(inFS.nextInt());
            }
        }
    }
    return mazePoints;
}
```

Complete(Demo) Project:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maze {
    
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Maze maze = new Maze();
      MazePoint[][]  mazePoints = maze.readMaze("twoDarray.txt");
      maze.print(mazePoints);
   }
   
   public MazePoint[][] readMaze(String fileToRead) throws Exception
   {
       FileInputStream fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(fileToRead);; // File input stream
       Scanner inFS= new Scanner(fileByteStream);// Scanner object
       int size = inFS.nextInt();
       MazePoint[][] mazePoints = new MazePoint[size][size];
       while(inFS.hasNext()) {
           for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
               for (int column = 0; column < size; column++) {
                   mazePoints[row][column] = new MazePoint();
                   mazePoints[row][column].setValue(inFS.nextInt());
               }
           }
       }
       return mazePoints;
   }
   
   public void print( MazePoint[][] mazePoints) {
       int size = mazePoints.length;
       for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
           for (int column = 0; column < size; column++) {
               System.out.print(mazePoints[row][column].getValue() + " ");
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
}

class MazePoint {
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Input File `twoDarray.txt`:

```
2 1 2 3 4
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: Hi, it looks better, I think they are the same type, but I get error: cannot convert from MazePoint[][] to MazePoint[][].

Comment: Can you share your MazePoint class?

Comment: I just try  maze.setValue(inFS.nextInt());
               mazePoints[row][column] = maze; there is still errors: Cannot invoke setValue(int) on the array type MazePoint[][]
 mazePoints cannot be resolved to a variable
 mazePoints cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Update answer portion with complete code. Try to run the full code and based on it modify your code. :)

Comment: If this helps you, then accept this answer. Please follow the link -https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers